# Lagrange theorem in a limit of a summation

Tags: limits, analysis, definite-integrals, summation

I need to evaluate
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$
The solution of this problem says that
$$\ln n = \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x$$
Then Lagrange's theorem is used to say that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \left[\color{red}{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{x-k}{\xi_k^2}}\right]\text{d}x$$
My problem is how the red part is obtained: I know that Lagrange theorem says, for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in the interval $[k,k+1]$ that exists $\xi_k\in(k,k+1)$ such that
$$-\frac{1}{\xi_k^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k}}{k+1-k}$$
I've done my calculations but I can't get the red part. Can someone explain me where it comes from?
Thanks.

Comment: Use 
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
with $f(x)=1/x$, $b=x$, $a=k$ and $c=\xi_k \in (k,x)$. Then solve for $1/x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't choose $b = k+1$, you should "let it loose" as $b=x$ within the interval $[k,k+1]$. Then, for some $\xi_k \in (k,x)$, you have by the mean value theorem
$$f'(\xi_k) = -\frac 1 {\xi_k^2} = \frac{f(x)-f(k)}{x-k} = \frac{\frac 1 x - \frac1 k}{x-k}. $$
Alternatively, you could expand the function $f$ at $x_0 = k$ as its Taylor polynomial with Lagrange remainder: for $x \in [k,k+1]$ there exists $\xi_k \in (x_0,x)$ such that
$$\frac 1 x = f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(\xi_k)(x-x_0) = \frac 1 k - \frac{1}{\xi_k^2}(x-k). $$
This is essentially the same solution (Lagrange remainder theorem is a generalization of the mean value theorem), but explains the red term in your question a little bit more directly.

Comment: How does this differ from DMH16 solution?

Comment: I hadn't loaded that comment when I posted my answer. Will delete if necessary

Comment: I've updated my answer with an "alternative" solution. @Denis28

Comment: @giobrach: So the intermediate value theorem for $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ can be used considering a point fixed (for instance the point $a$) and a variable point $x$ in the interval $[a,b]$? I didn't think it was possible, since the theorem is enunced with a fixed interval $[a,b]$, so I thought it could be used only with fixed $a$ and $b$. Indeed I don't see any problems, but when I see $[a,b]$ I automatically think that $a$ and $b$ must be fixed. Why does this work then?

Answer (score 3):

$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{k} \frac{1}{n} =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\ln n}  \int_{1}^n \frac{1}{x} dx$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\ln n}=1.$$